# understanding on changefeed in cosmos db

Tags: azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

below is my code, where I am trying to copy certain documents from one container to another. I am using Azure function with Cosmos db trigger with changefeed. When I run it in debug mode i am not getting any document and in the console it is showing at Host locked state which means there is no new document to read. As per my understanding, the azure function should read from beginning in my first run and then in subsequent run it should start from where it left by reading the token in lease container. Looking for experts to confirm on this and what can be reason that I am not reading any items here?? I put the debugger point at very first line but its not hitting it.

```
[FunctionName( "MigrateWithChangeFeed" )]
        public static async Task Run( [CosmosDBTrigger(
            databaseName: "sourcedb",
            collectionName: "collec1",
            StartFromBeginning = true,
            ConnectionStringSetting = "CosmosDBConnection",
            LeaseCollectionName = "leases",            
            CreateLeaseCollectionIfNotExists = true
    )] IReadOnlyList<Document> source,
    ILogger log )
        {           
            Uri taskCollectionUri = UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri( source_databaseId, source_containerId );
            DocumentClient client = new DocumentClient( new Uri( _endpointUrl ), _primaryKey );
            if( source != null && source.Count > 0 )
            {
                foreach( var item in source )
                {
                    string customerName = string.Empty;
                    var jsonContent = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject( item.ToString() );
                    if( !string.IsNullOrEmpty( (string)jsonContent["ClassId"] ) )
                    {
                        customerName = (string)jsonContent["Customer"];
                        if( string.IsNullOrEmpty( customerName ) )
                        {
                            customerName = projectCustomerNameMapping
                                .FirstOrDefault( q => q.Key.IndexOf( (string)jsonContent["Project"] ) != -1 ||
                                ((string)jsonContent["Project"]).IndexOf( q.Key ) != -1 ).Value ?? "Unknown";
                        }
                        string partitionkeyValue = string.Concat( (string)jsonContent["ClassId"],
                            "|",
                            (string)jsonContent["Project"],
                            "|",
                            customerName );
                        jsonContent.Add( new JProperty( "PartitionKey", partitionkeyValue ) );
                        await client.CreateDocumentAsync( UriFactory.CreateDocumentCollectionUri(
                       source_databaseId, target_containerId ),
                       jsonContent );
                    }

                }
            }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, please do not create a `DocumentClient` inside the Function, you should be using a singleton/static instance, otherwise you will be running out of available connections pretty fast. Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/azure-functions/manage-connections#static-clients

How the Change Feed works is that, the first ever time you run this Function, it will read From the Beginning (basically reading all existing documents in the monitored collection), after that (assuming it's still running), it will pickup any newly created or updated document. The Trigger basically checks for the lease collection containing documents that mark the previously stored checkpoints, if there are none, it means it's the first time starting, so it honors the StartFromBeginning flag, afterward, when there are documents, it ignores it.

Keep in mind though, that if you are running this Function locally AND also you have a deployment in the cloud, then they act as multiple instances of the same Function (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/troubleshoot-changefeed-functions#some-changes-are-missing-in-my-trigger) unless each one is using a different lease collection or using a lease prefix (https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-create-multiple-cosmos-db-triggers).

Comment: so I have published and deployed the function in cloud but then i have disabled it there. and for testing I am debugging it locally but it doesn't take any recordings. I get the message "Host.." which means no new record to read

Comment: Try adding a different LeasePrefix to your local Function, if that works, it means the one deployed seems to be still running (or there is one running somewhere else with the same configuration you are using locally)